# Список 'a', 'b', '_', 'c', 'd' в строку ab cd

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список

Нужно список ['a', 'b', '_', 'c', 'd'] превратить в строку - "ab cd". Если это вообще возможно. Если не возможно, то скажите пожалуйста, как бы вы решили эту задачу:

Split the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters, then the missing second character of the final pair should be replaced with an underscore ('_').

Input: A string.

Output: An iterable of strings.

Precondition: 0<=len(str)<=100

Comment: Показали бы свои попытки :) А так: **1)** объединить список в строку **2)** заменить `_` на ` `

Comment: Только что понял как решить, лучше бы я этот вопрос не задавал, а сам подумал ещё минут 5. Просто на сайте с тестами строка автоматом в список превращалась, хотя в функции этого не указано. И когда я например писал "".join(mass) вместо строки - опять список. А как тут плюс ставить). Всё таки если бы я не понял, ваш ответ мне бы помог.

Comment: У ответа есть стрелка вверх (плюс) и галочка(принять ответ), справка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Но вообще там где на английском написано задача состоит в другом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте это можно решить вот так

```
a = ['a', 'b', '_', 'c', 'd']

b = "".join(a).replace("_", " ")

print(b)
```

join - объединяем  строку
replace - меняем "_" на пробел

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался! А как тут плюс поставить?

Comment: галочку около ответа

Comment: обращайтесь, вам всегда помогут

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо. Через 2 минуты поставлю галочку. А то пока что не даёт.